# Access to DOM elements by ID in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to handle disable attribute of input elements by ID in my React app

It's possible with states but number of elements is not fixed, maybe 10 input or 20 or more ...

I've decided to set ID for each input and access to them with ID, for example :

```js
document.getElementById('title-12') ....
```

So, is it a suitable trick or best practice to handle this issue ?

Performance and clean code is very important for me :-)

Thanks

Comment: No, not at all. You must not be manipulating Real DOM in any form while using ReactJS, as main benefit of reactJS is that it handles real DOM itself and allows the programmer to just manipulate on virtual DOM. In case you try to manipulate the Real DOM than your changes could be overwritten as soon as re-render of React is fired.

Comment: Would it not be better to give all the titles the same class. Then get all of the titles using getElementsByClassName. Loop through the node list you get back from this and apply your logic?

Comment: If the number of elements is not fixed, then you can maintain the array of elements. Whenever you add one element, you need to push that element in an array. In the render method, you just need to loop through that array which will show the dynamic elements. To toggle the disable input, you can maintain value  in that array.

Comment: It's possible, but directly goes against the idea of React, your 10-20 elements could each be a component with state, or part of a container component that manages their attributes.

Comment: Your `render` function determines what is displayed. You shouldn't be directly changing the DOM.

Comment: @RAGHVENDERKATARIA In fact I'm trying to create an Addable form witn unlimited inputs ... I need disable attribute for handle nested drop downs. first user must select a category and then sub category and next steps ....

Comment: @Nagesh I can't store elements into Array, because I need to have onChange event and if I store elements into array in future I can't use onChangefor nested drop downs !

Comment: @Alex Storing elements in an array mean you just need to store the value for that input(element). It will be the multidimensional array which will have the value and the disabled flag. In the render method, you have to loop through that array then show the input field with the value and disabled attribute. You can add the onClick event with the current index of the array.

Comment: @Alex you need to change your mindset, React does not manipulate html ( DOM ), you generate html using javascript. Handle whatever you need to in your code, and render() it on your screen in desired fashion

Comment: @Nagesh but how about delete button ? I want to create an addable, in this case I've add and delete button. when I add new item = in fact I've pushing an item into state array. for delete I cant't use array.filter , because my loop will generate elements from 0 to length of that array and it will not suitable for this case !!!

Comment: @Alex for deleting, please using the onClick event and pass the current index of the element. I the delete event listener method, you have to remove the array element by using the index.

Comment: @Nagesh Thanks, but I think it's not suitable, because I'm using Fromik to handle inputs, if I delete an index from state array it's not the end of story ! because I must use DOM removeElement to remove that input from form and clean delete items ...

Comment: Again, that's not how React works. Your component "view" is dependent on its state/props. If you don't want an input to appear you need to store that information in state so that your form can be rendered without it.

Answer (score 2):

Oops... my bad. I digged into your discussion and here's a new solution.

That's still correct that React approach is advised so we should use reusable components for inputs (we can have any number of inputs right now). All the input's data are stored in parent component's store as a collection. We map through collection and send properties to each component (in the simplest version - `id`, `isDisabled` and `disableInput()` function).

```
class Titles extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titles: [
        {
          id: 0,
          disabled: true
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          disabled: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  addNewInput = () => {
    const prevList = this.state.titles;
    const newItem = {
      id: prevList.length,
      disabled: false
    };
    this.setState({ titles: [...prevList, newItem] });
  };

  disableInput = id => {
    const titles = this.state.titles;
    titles[id].disabled = !titles[id].disabled;
    this.setState({ titles });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Titles list</h1>
        <form style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
          {this.state.titles.map(title => (
            <Title
              key={title.id}
              id={title.id}
              isDisabled={title.disabled}
              disableInput={id => this.disableInput(id)}
            />
          ))}
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => this.addNewInput()}>Dodaj nowy</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

in `Title` component we just render the props in to `<input>` and a button with `onClick` function that sends `id` of this component to its parent, where disable attribute's value is being reversed.

```
const Title = ({ id, isDisabled, disableInput }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id={id}
        type="text"
        placeholder={id}
        disabled={isDisabled}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => disableInput(id)}>
        disable input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Working example can be found here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-gwoth)

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: as I said, i want a trick to handle a lot of fields, so ... I can't make ref for tens or thousands inputs !

Comment: If it's not a satisfying answer for you or it's not matching your problem, please let me know.